# Adding prev/next buttons in Vegas slider

Tags: javascript, slider, vegasjs

I have a simple slider which slides a few images and is using `Vegas JS`. This is what I have

```
<section class="slider fullwidth">

   <div class="caption"></div>

   <div id="buttons">
      <a href="#" id="previous"></a>
      <a href="#" id="next"></a>    
   </div>
</section>
$(".slider").vegas({
      slides: [
          { src: "slide-1.jpg", text: "Text 1" },
          { src: "slide-2.jpg", text: "Text 2" }
      ],
      walk: function (index, slideSettings) {
          $('.caption').html(slideSettings.text);
      }
});

$('#previous').on('click', function () {
    $elmt.vegas('options', 'transition', 'slideRight2').vegas('previous');
});

$('#next').on('click', function () {
    $elmt.vegas('options', 'transition', 'slideLeft2').vegas('next');
});
```

The code above produces the slider and both slides + the caption are changed but the buttons are not working.

When I click on Next or Previous the error that I get in the console is

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $elmt is not defined

I have tried to follow their documentation here: https://vegas.jaysalvat.com/documentation/methods/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `$elmt.vegas` try to use `$(".slider").vegas`

Comment: I've got another error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).vegas is not a function`

Comment: please check you have include the  `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> <script src="http://jaysalvat.github.io/vegas/releases/latest/vegas.js"></script>` if  yes then write your script below these code, I may help

Comment: Yes, I have them, as I said in my question the slider is working fine. Just the prev/next buttons doesn't work.